# Rails 3 - RMagick doesn't find libfreetype.6.dylib using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, x11, rmagick

I'm trying to use Paperclip to upload some image. It's work fine but if I want add some style with :

```
:styles => { :small => "100x100" }
```

It does not work anymore, I have this error message :

> *myImage* is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

So, I've found some tips on the web and I've installed ImageMagick with Brew then I've added

```
gem 'Rmagick'
```

to my GemFile.

And now when I restart my server, I get this message error :

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (LoadError)
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: libMagickCore.5.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 10.0.0 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle

I've updated my X11 and installed XQuartz, but nothing to do it's doesn't work anymore.
I can restart rails server if I remove

```
gem 'Rmagick'
```

from my GemFile.

Any ideas ?

Thank you very much, I've spent 10 hours on this bug without figure out it !!

Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate your libfreetype.6.dylib eg:

```
sudo find / -name "libfreetype.6.dylib" -print
```

Make sure that your version is 14.0.0 or later (the above is my path on macosx) eg:

```
otool -L /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
```

If the version is right, maybe you have a library path problem.

Otherwise an update will fix.

Comment: Oh man ! You are my hero !! I've fixed it
I didn't know what update, but I've found this lib with good version in an other folder, I've just replaced it ;)
Thanks you !

Comment: thx man you helped me solved bit unrelated problem with [Rmagick has not found libMagickCore.5.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040932/rmagick-complaining-about-libmagickcore-5-dylib-not-found-in-osx/19040933#19040933)