# Rails + Mac OS X: libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion, rake, rmagick

If I run some kind of `rake` command, I get this error message:

```
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib requires version 16.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0 - /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.bundle
...
```

I am running on RoR 3.2, OSX Lion.

Could anyone help me, please, how to fix this issue? I spent 2 days of googling, reading discussions, but unfortunately with zero success...

Thank you so much!

Comment: same issue although I'm on OSX 10.8.2, ruby 1.8.7, rmagick 2.9.1. ImageMagick was installed using homebrew, i.e. brew install imagemagick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an amazing how-to-install-rmagick that have been working beautifully for me, try to re-install ImageMagick following these steps:

1. `yum install tcl-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel ghostscript-devel bzip2-devel freetype-devel libtiff-devel -y` (I use CentOS, you can translate the commands to your distro)
2. Download ImageMagick. Write `wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz` and press Enter. ImageMagick.tar.gz is created in the current directory.
3. Unpack the ImageMagick archive. Write `tar xczf ImageMagick.tar.gz` and press Enter. A new directory, ImageMagick-version, where version is the ImageMagick version number, is created.
4. Switch to the ImageMagick directory. Write cd ImageMagick-version and press Enter.
5. Configure the ImageMagick build. Write `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --without-perl` and press Enter.
6. Compile ImageMagick. Write `make` and press Enter. ImageMagick compiles. This step may take several minutes.
7. Install ImageMagick to your home directory. Write `make install` and press Enter.
8. Remove the installation files. Write `rm -r ImageMagick.tar.gz` and press Enter.
9. Add /usr/local/bin to your PATH.

   - Write `echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile` and press Enter.
   - Reload your .bash_profile. Write `source ~/.bash_profile` and press Enter.
10. Install the RMagick gem.

    - Write `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` and press Enter.
    - Write `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/` and press Enter.
    - Install the RMagick gem in your Ruby on Rails application.

Tell me later how it goes.

Answer (score 11):

Using Homebrew I was able to solve it using the following commands:

```
brew uninstall freetype
brew update
brew install freetype
```

Update step might be unnecessary. The installation succeeded but with the following warning:

```
Warning: Could not link freetype. Unlinking...
```

So one final command:

```
brew link --overwrite freetype
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use something like [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh/) or [`MacPorts`](https://www.macports.org/) to manage external library dependencies?

Installing the `imagemagick` library from there and then install rmagick.

Comment: When I run `brew install imagemagick`, I will get `Error: imagemagick-6.8.0-10 already installed` and I just successfully installed the `rmagick-2.13.1`... where could be then a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another post:

[Rails 3 - RMagick doesn't find libfreetype.6.dylib using Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346697/rails-3-rmagick-doesnt-find-libfreetype-6-dylib-using-paperclip)

I performed the search and found that there was an older version of libfreetype that was being referenced and newer versions hidden elsewhere. By copying/linking the newer versions into the appropriate directory (/usr/local/lib in my case) the problem was resolved.