# RMagick complaining about libMagickCore.5.dylib not found in OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, homebrew

after running `brew upgrade imagemagick`, when I run `rails s` I'll get

```
/Users/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@ezaaa/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': dlopen(/Users/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@ezaaa/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@ezaaa/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@ezaaa/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
```

I'm using Carrierwave gem with RMagick,  OS is OSX Moutain Lion

Comment: When `brew upgrade imagemagick` breaks rails, it usually just means your rmagick gem has to be upgraded to a newer version as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

thx to bit unrelated answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346697/rails-3-rmagick-doesnt-find-libfreetype-6-dylib-using-paperclip) I manage to fix this by:

1/ search for this lib in the system

```
sudo find / -name "libMagickCore.5.dylib" -print
```

I found mine in `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib`

2/ link this library to required path

```
ln /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib
```

Comment: similar problem fixed for libltdl.7.dylib `ln /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/lib/libltdl.7.dylib /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib`

Answer (score 31):

Anyone else struggling with this right now (Jan 2017) - RMagick 2.15.4 can't be built with ImageMagick 7.0.x

First, please do this:

```
brew uninstall ImageMagick
gem uninstall rmagick
```

Second, please see https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/256 and read the answer by hristozov, viz:

```
brew rm imagemagick
cd "$(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/"
git checkout 6f014f2b7f1f9e618fd5c0ae9c93befea671f8be imagemagick.rb
brew install imagemagick
brew pin imagemagick
git reset --hard
```

This will force homebrew to use /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.7-3

Third,

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Yep. Jan 2017 and I was struggling with this. Thanks. It worked.

Comment: Yes, this worked also for me. The right steps should however be:

1. `brew uninstall ImageMagick`
2. `gem uninstall rmagick` (all versions)
3. <do the steps above to install the working version of ImageMagick>
4. `gem install rmagick`

worked for me

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti thanks I have incorporated your comments in the answer

Comment: Great stuff @PeteW! This is the only thing that worked for me after a day of issue <3

Answer (score 18):

1 brew uninstall ImageMagick

2 brew install ImageMagick

3 gem uninstall rmagick 
(all versions)

4 gem install rmagick

worked for me

Comment: This works for me.  It seems a proper solution than sudo symlinking some library file.

Comment: perfect, this worked for me in 2021 with Rails 5 so is still relevant. simplest solution to get a clean install of everything

Answer (score 16):

Just this helped me:

```
gem pristine rmagick
```

Thanks to https://github.com/mroth/lolcommits/issues/9#issuecomment-5153570

Comment: could be. Just to be aware: `gem pristine XXXX` is for  reversing any changes developer done to locally installed gem. E.g. if you were debugging a locally installed gem and you forgot to remove `binding.pry`

Comment: Thanks, man resolve the issue after this :)

Answer (score 4):

Big thanks! I had the same problem:

```
$ perl -le 'use Image::Magick'
```

> Can't load
>   '/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle'
>   for module Image::Magick:
>   dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle,
>   1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle
>   Reason: image not found at
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm
>   line 194.  at -e line 1. Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
>   &Image::Magick::constant not defined. The required ImageMagick
>   libraries are not installed or not installed properly. END
>   failed--call queue aborted at -e line 1.

And after:

```
$ sudo find / -name "libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib" -print
```

> /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib

I created a symlink:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib
```

And removed and installed all the imagemagick dependences:

```
$ brew install perlmagick
```

> ==> Installing dependencies for perlmagick: libpng, imagemagick

And everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed for by running
`gem uninstall rmagick`
and
`gem install rmagick`